# Multiple level of route not working in Express

Tags: express, web, routes

I am working on a project similar to an e-commerce website but much more simpler using express, mongoose, ejs. Currently, I am working on "creating new items" part.

/items shows all the items in the system(I only have 20-30 items in total)

The problem is that when I try to go to /items/new program terminates with very very long error that I cannot even see the first line of the error message.

```
app.get("/items/new", (req, res) => {
    res.render('items/new');
})
```

However, when I use the below code it works.

```
app.get("/newitem", (req, res) => {
    res.render('items/new');
})
```

I do not understand the reason. I would be very glad if some can explain.

Comment: What's the error? How can we reproduce it?